# Django - ChoiceField Spanning Multiple Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is it possible in django to have a ChoiceField on a formset level rather than an inline form? So for example if I have a formset for phones and each inline form represents a single `Phone` model, how can I have a ChoiceField that spans all the inline forms? Something like this where I'm choosing a primary phone:

[image: Complex ChoiceField]

My models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    primary_phone = models.OneToOneField('Phone', related_name='is_primary', null=True, blank=True)

class Phone(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, editable=False)
    type = models.CharField(choices=PHONE_TYPES, max_length=16)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @property
    def is_primary(self):
        return profile.primary_phone == self
```

I can always remove `primary_phone` and use a BooleanField in `Phone` to indicate if it's primary or not, but I'm not sure if this going to help my problem.

I'm also looking for a less-hacky more-django-like approach if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have django create this for you automatically.  In your ModelForm (that's used in the inline) I'd add a boolean field called is_primary.  This field will then show up on each inlined Phone instance (as a checkbox).

On the front end sort it out with javascript so that a user can only select one default at a time.  On the back end use some custom validation to double check that only one is_default was submitted, and then update the primary_phone as necessary with form logic.

Comment: I have been told to go with this approach before, but I still don't get one aspect of it. Why would you want to use checkboxes with javascript instead of radio buttons? I mean I can do the same manual work but use radio buttons and no javascript. Any specific reason you prefer checkboxes?

Comment: Well the boolean field is going to generate checkboxes by default, and I can't offhand think of a way to get django to produce a radio button group that spans multiple models.  I think it's highly unlikely to be possible since django is going to append a prefix to the name of each.

Peronally I see no issue with using checkboxes and using javascript to make them act like radio buttons.